# Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 Nautilus local search

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 17.04

I used to use search by keyboard in Nautilus for quickly selecting folder in directory by just imputing the first few letters. However in Ubuntu gnome this function is replaced by a global search. Is there any way to revert the behavior to standard?